# Calling Invoke within a public static function Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, invoke, static-functions

I'm getting an error that I don't understand. The simplified version of my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
public class RunLater : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static void Do()
    {
        Invoke("RunThisLater", 2.0f);
    }

    public void RunThisLater()
    {
        Debug.Log("This will run later");
    }

}
```

Comment: Right "runthislater" is not static, therefore inside your class you have no instance to call runthislater on..

Comment: BugFinder so what should i do now? make RunThisLater static as well or remove Static from Do funciton?

Comment: well it will in part depend on what you intend to do with it later.....

Comment: You can pass a reference to to the owning object... For example when you call Do you could pass a parameter to your monobheaviour like Do(myBehaviour) of course you would need to modify your method to take in a parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it in as a parameter like this:

```
public class RunLater : MonoBehaviour
{            
    public static void Do(RunLater instance)
    {
        instance.Invoke("RunThisLater", 2.0f);
    }

    public void RunThisLater()
    {
       Debug.Log("This will run later");
    }
}
```

Comment: and if I wanted to call this from another class then how I'm gonna call?

Comment: then you have to get the instance from hierarchy.... and pass it in.  No matter how you do it; if you want to call an instance method from inside a static method you WILL need access to the instance.  The other choice you have is to NOT make your method static and just get a reference to your instance from the other class using GetComponent or Find or FindWithTag... or similar.

Answer (score -1):

One approach is to have the static parts of the class store a MonoBehaviour reference to itself. Like so:

```
public class RunLater : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static RunLater selfReference = null;

    public static void Do()
    {
        InitSelfReference();
        selfReference.DoInstanced();
    }

    static void InitSelfReference()
    {
        if (selfReference == null)
        {
            // We're presuming you only have RunLater once in the entire hierarchy.
            selfReference = Object.FindObjectOfType<RunLater>();
        }
    }

    public void DoInstanced()
    {
        Invoke("RunThisLater", 2f);
    }

    void RunThisLater()
    {
        Debug.Log("This will run later");
    }
}
```

You would now be able to call RunLater.Do() from anywhere in your code of other gameObjects. Good luck!

Comment: Though the name `selfReference` is a bit misleading .. it should rather be `instance` or `singleton` since this is what it actually is.

Comment: This only works if the MonoBehaviour is a singleton.... What if you have many instances of the same script?

Comment: @derHugo Maybe `selfInstance`? (To clarify of what it is an instance.)

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro Yeah you're right, and I had tried to clarify that restriction -- in case it was enough for the asker -- in my code comment.